# Conditional width and precision using printf

Tags: haskell

I'm want to print as follows:

```
1.0 -> 1
18.0 -> 18
370.0 -> 370
1.2 -> 1.2
3.4 -> 3.4
```

In other words, print as a whole number when the mantissa is 0.0, otherwise print as a float with precision 1. I can check if the float is actually an integer and print accordingly, but is there a way to make printf do it?
I checked that `printf "%2f" 10.0` prints `10.0`, so, it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
fmt :: Float -> String
fmt x = if int then show y else printf "%.1f" x
  where
    y = round x :: Int
    int = abs (x - fromIntegral y) < 0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Hackage docs, you may not be able to achieve this with `printf` directly. Taken from the docs:

> Haskell [printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Text-Printf.html#v:printf) will place a zero after a decimal point when possible.

If you absolutely require the trailing `.0` to be stripped you may need to look at an alternate means of formatting your data. As a quick and dirty hack, you could use `floatToDigits` from `Numeric`:

```hs
import Numeric (floatToDigits)
showFloat :: RealFloat a => a -> String
showFloat n = (concat $ map show prefix) <>
              separator                  <>
              (concat $ map show suffix)
  where
    (digits, precision) = floatToDigits 10 n
    (prefix, suffix)    = splitAt precision digits
    separator           = if null suffix then "" else "."

main = do
  putStrLn $ showFloat (0.123 :: Float) -- 0.123
  putStrLn $ showFloat (1.230 :: Float) -- 1.23
  putStrLn $ showFloat (12.30 :: Float) -- 12.3
  putStrLn $ showFloat (123.0 :: Float) -- 123
```

Comment: I posted a [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72964074/839733).

Comment: Ah, didn't see your restriction of precision being limited to 1; in that case, your solution is a lot more concise!

Answer (score 1):

My [`pragmatic-show`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pragmatic-show) package has an alternative `Show` class (and corresponding `print`) whose floating-point instances give all the examples you asked as the default behaviour.

```
$ cabal new-repl --build-depends 'pragmatic-show'
...
> import qualified Text.Show.Pragmatic as SP
> SP.print 1.0
1
> SP.print 18.0
18
> SP.print 370.0
370
> SP.print 1.2
1.2
> SP.print 3.4
3.4
```

Note that unlike your ad-hoc solution, it does *not* squelsh small-but-significant fractional parts:

```
> SP.print 5.0000245
5.0000245
```

It does however squelch the kind of tiny floating point deviations that turn up almost inevitably in any calculation that should analytically give an integer:

```
> SP.print $ 1 + sin pi
1
> Prelude.print $ 1 + sin pi
1.0000000000000002
```

Comment: I can only use a set of predefined packages for this exercise, but I’ll  keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Does your package allow for custom formatting like printf does?

Answer (score -2):

`%g` uses the shortest representation.

Floating-point numbers usually aren't stored as a number in base 10, but 2 (performance, size, practicality reasons). However, whatever the base of your representation, there will always be rational numbers that will not be expressible in some arbitrary size limit for the variable to store them.

If the shortest representation has more than `16` digits, printf will shorten the number string by cutting cut the `2` digit at the very end, leaving you with `3122.550000000000`, which is actually `3122.55` in the shortest form, explaining the result you obtained.

In general, `%g` will always give you the shortest result possible, meaning that if the sequence of digits representing your number can be shortened without any loss of precision, it will be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double x = 123.0;
    printf("%e\n", x);
    printf("%f\n", x);
    printf("%g\n", x);

    double y = 123.10;
    printf("%e\n", y);
    printf("%f\n", y);
    printf("%g\n", y);
}
```

Output:

```
1.230000e+02
123.000000
123

1.231000e+02
123.100000
123.1
```

Comment: I believe your answer is in C, and not Haskell, which the question is tagged with.

Comment: In C perhaps, but not Haskell; `printf "%g" (1.0 :: Float)` yields `1.0` as its output, which is not the desired output of `1`.